# Updating Firebase with API

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, api, firebase-realtime-database

I am receiving an undefined error each time I try to grad some nested data within an XML file. I am using a node server to update Firebase and grabbing the data from a sports api. Below is the XML and I am trying to get the yardLine number from the situation node.

```html
<game xmlns="http://feed.elasticstats.com/schema/nfl/premium/boxscore-v4.0.xsd" id="f37339c3-6d36-47ba-932b-8973dd6e5dda" status="inprogress" reference="57265" number="32" scheduled="2017-09-19T00:30:00+00:00" attendance="0" utc_offset="-5" entry_mode="INGEST" weather="Cloudy Temp: 72 F, Humidity: 80%, Wind: ENE 5 mph" clock="15:00" quarter="1">
  <summary>
    <season id="3cf0e8ec-048d-4872-a706-b248c198831c" year="2017" type="REG" name="REG"/>
  </summary>
  <situation clock="15:00" down="1" yfd="10">
    <possession id="04aa1c9d-66da-489d-b16a-1dee3f2eec4d" name="Giants" market="New York" alias="NYG" reference="5030"/>
    <location id="c5a59daa-53a7-4de0-851f-fb12be893e9e" name="Lions" market="Detroit" alias="DET" reference="5019" yardline="18"/>
  </situation>
```

I have tried (game.situation.location.yardLine) and game.situation.location[5]

but I am getting undefined for both.

Answer (score 0):

I had yardLine in camel case when it should have been all lower case.